# Lucene Version

Tags: lucene.net

Has anybody heard of the Lucene version 2.3.1.3?
We're using it in a production project.
However the stable version of Lucene version 2.0.0.4.

Should I push to have the project's dependencies moved to version 2.0.0.4?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) or [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)?  These are different but related projects.  Lucene.NET is a .NET port of the Lucene Java code.

[2.0.0.4](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/download/) is the stable version of Lucene.NET.

However, there is a version 2.3.1 of Lucene (for Java).  The Lucene Website makes it seem like [2.4.1](http://lucene.apache.org/#9+March+2009+-+Lucene+Java+2.4.1+available) is the most recent release suitable for production.

Comment: It's Lucene.net, and the version, at least according to its properties, is 2.3.1.3. I'm guessing it was compiled from the latest development branch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running 2.3.1.3 over here in production at about 50 sites.
I wouldn't recommend downgrading the version as a lot of performance and memory leak issues are adressed in 2.3.1.